# How to convert Python 3 script into Windows exe file using cx_Freeze

Tags: python

I am trying to do something, which given Python's prevalence, should be easy: convert my .py script into a Windows .exe  file.

I have spent countless hours with pyinstaller and p2exe, but they don't work for me.  Therefore I am trying to use cx_Freeze.  My script is called sebzo.py and associated with it, in the folder wavFiles, are several .wav files.

I downloaded cx_Freeze by using Anaconda and the command:
conda install -c pyzo cx_freeze=5.0 to re-download cx_Freeze.  cx_Freeze and related files ended up in c: Users\Owen Walker\Lib\site-packages.

Then I wrote a setup.py file as advised by various websites and placed sebzo.py, setup.py, and the subfolder wavFiles--in the folder: Users\Owen Walker\Lib\site-packages.

Then on the Windows 10 command line, in c: Users\Owen Walker\Lib\site-packages, I entered the command: "python setup.py build", and got the error: "File "setup.py", line 2 in  from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable ImportError: cannot import name 'setup'"

The setup.py file reads:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
setup(
    name = "sebzo",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "arithmetic practice program",
    executables = [Executable("sebzo.py")],
    )
```

I don't know what the error means or how to fix it.